# Giving descriptive test names to Mojolicious tests?

Tags: perl, testing, mojolicious

I'm tidying up my Mojolicious tests and giving them properly descriptive names. As an example:

```
$t->get_ok( '/api/ninjablock', 'Run a GET against /api/ninjablock with no credentials' )
     ->status_is( 403, '  and it has correctly returned a 403' );
```

The test output looks like this, however:

```
ok 1 - GET /api/ninjablock
ok 2 -   and it has correctly returned a 403
```

I assume I'm missing something obvious, but how do I make that first test show something other than `GET /api/ninjablock` as the name?

Comment: get_ok: from the docs, I do not think that is supposed to work, it says "same arguments as "get" in Mojo::UserAgent", no mention of additional parameter for naming the test. get() takes additional parameters, though, so that may be the reason why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Test::Mojo source code](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Test/Mojo.txt), `get_ok()` only accepts three parameters, `($self, $method, $url)`. Hence, with `Test::Mojo` itself, you cannot assign a description to your test the way it is currently.

It's a bit unfortunate that you can't supply descriptions, but you can wrap any test you like in `Test::More`'s `ok()`, `is()`, etc. subroutines.

Don't be afraid to take it up to a higher level as well. If you need to test that several URLs return 403 when you don't supply credentials:

```
ok($t->get_ok($_)->status_is(403) => "$_ no creds : 403") for @urls;
```

Note that this will result in an extra line of test output (or an extra test number), but most of the time you should be running in a harness anyway, so only the tests that fail will display. You can consider `Test::Group` if you need a bit of extra organization.

Comment: Ahh, perfect. Thanks a lot!